# Cocoa - NSCursor resets to the default cursor when a key is pressed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscursor

I'm working on an application that has a window with a fully sized NSOpenGLView. I'm using [view addCursorRect] and [cursor set] to show a custom cursor, but when I press any key on the keyboard, the cursor resets to the default arrow. I've also tried overriding resetCursorRects and calling invalidateCursorRects when a key is pressed, which results in a flickering cursor.

The cursor switches back to my custom cursor when I click anywhere in the view, so I suppose the keyboard presses somehow unfocus my view. Is there any way to prevent the view from becoming unfocused when I press a key?

Comment: could you post some sample code?  I do a lot of this in my code, but I am not having the same problem you are describing.  I just want to see how you are setting things up maybe we can figure this out ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember your cursor settings + when you need to reset call e.g refreshCursor method. Example implementation:

```
- (void)refreshCursor
{
    NSCursor *cursor = nil;
    if ([self graphic]) {
        cursor = [graphic hoverCursorForPoint:[self mousePosition]];
    } else if ([self group]){
        cursor = [NSCursor openHandCursor];
    }
    [self setHoverCursor:cursor];
    [self refresh];
}

- (void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    [super updateTrackingAreas];
    [self removeTrackingArea:[self trackingArea]];
    NSTrackingArea *area = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self visibleRect]
                                                        options:NSTrackingActiveAlways|NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited|NSTrackingMouseMoved
                                                          owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self setTrackingArea:area];
    [self addTrackingArea:[self trackingArea]];
}

- (void)setCursorRects
{
    [self discardCursorRects];
    if ([self hoverCursor]) {
        [self addCursorRect:[self visibleRect] cursor:[self hoverCursor]];
    }
}

- (void)setHoverCursor:(NSCursor *)hoverCursor {
    if (_hoverCursor != hoverCursor) {
        _hoverCursor = hoverCursor;
        [self setCursorRects];
    }
}

- (void)resetCursorRects {
    [super resetCursorRects];
    [self setCursorRects];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [[NSCursor currentSystemCursor] set];
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [self refreshCursor];
}

- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)event
{
  [self refreshCursor];
}

//allow key events
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```